# Tautology And Substitution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $ \alpha $ be some proposition, and let $ A = \alpha $, and let $ B = \neg \alpha $.

Is the statement $ A \lor B $ a tautology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $α ∨ ¬α$ is a *tautology*.

But - in general - $A∨B$ is not a tautology.

The "rule" is:

> every *instance* of a *tautological schema* will be a tautology.

In other words, given a tautological schema, like $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$, every formula obtained via substitution from it, like $p_1 \lor \lnot p_1$ or $\forall x Q(x) \lor \lnot \forall x Q(x)$, will be a tautology.

Comment: So letters (or symbols) have to be independent in a sense that they don't contradict?

Comment: @Joseph - we have to take care about the difference between formula of the (formal) language, made with connectives and propositional letters (or variables): $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ and schema of the meta-language, like e.g. $A \lor \lnot A$ where $A$ stay for a *formula*.